# What happens to foreground actions if there's no WatchKit app?

Tags: apple-watch

According to the documentation, when a notification gets shown on Apple Watch, and a user clicks on a foreground action, it will launch the WatchKit app. So what happens in this case if you don't have a WatchKit app, just a normal iOS app?

Comment: It gives you the option to dismiss it.

Comment: As in some kind of pop up comes up and tells you the action isn't supported and gives you the option to dismiss the alert?

Comment: No, it gives you the first part of the notification and gives you the option to dismiss it.

Comment: Oh so it wouldn't even show the foreground action as on option on the watch? (that would be perfect!)

Comment: What do you mean by foreground action? If you mean that you can't do anything but view and dismiss it, then yes.

Comment: I mean you can add action buttons to normal phone notifications, and a foreground action button is one that launches the main app to perform some action (this is different from just clicking on a notification). According to the documentation, if such an action is clicked on the watch, it goes to the watchkit app. But what happens if you don't have a watchkit app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior I see is that `Foreground` actions are not shown to the user on the watch if there is no Apple Watch app.

This seems reasonable since [Apple's documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html) says

> Foreground actions launch your Watch app